# Monitoring PSUs with local IPMI and Nagios

Tags: nagios, ipmi

I'd like to use Nagios to monitor the redundant PSUs in my servers (running Debian Wheezy).

I've run the `sensors-detect` script in the `lm-sensors` package, and the only thing it can find is

```
Driver `ipmisensors':
  * ISA bus, address 0xca2
    Chip `IPMI BMC KCS' (confidence: 8)
```

I then installed `freeipmi-tools`, and I find that I can get some useful output from `ipmi-sensors`:

```
$ sudo ipmi-sensors --group='Power Supply'
5: Power Supply 1 (Power Supply): [Presence detected]
6: Power Supply 2 (Power Supply): [Presence detected]
7: Power Supplies (Power Supply): [Fully Redundant]
```

I can write a Nagios plugin to run `ipmi-sensors` locally, parse its output, and alert if it changes, but I'm reluctant to rely on the output format staying the same, and I can't figure out how to get more machine-readable output.

I've looked at [check_ipmi_sensor](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/IPMI_Sensor_Monitoring_Plugin), but it seems only to operate where the IPMI device is available on the network; mine is not.

Is there a better way than parsing the output of `ipmi-sensors`?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with Nagios, but I'd be really surprised if someone hasn't written a plugin or whatever it's called for local IPMI devices already. This is a common way to monitor hardware.

Comment: Me too :) I suspect my <search engine>-foo isn't good enough on a Friday afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

There are several other plugins for IPMI listed in Nagios Exchange. This is (sometimes) a better place to start looking than Google.

For example:

- [check_ipmi](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/Dell/check_ipmi/details) can operate on localhost, using `ipmitool`
- [check_ipmi.py](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/check_ipmi-2Epy/details) also localhost, using `free-ipmi`

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason to parse the IPMI data. It takes a CPU thread to read and a thread to parse and if you are scaling to data center size systems, thousands of servers thats a lot of threads. Instead use an API,  java(Vrx or Hemi) or C library(ipmitool or freeipmi) to access the IPMI data directly. Data Centers (40 k servers) can read 6 million IPMI sensors/minute and thread creation becomes the limiting factor.

The advantage an API is that IPMB bus wirte errors, as in the bus is busy or has a permement hardware error are reported and you can decide to retry retrieving the data.